# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Support for Asus Z97 Deluxe Motherboard

Tags: 14.04, asus

I'm planning to purchase an [Asus Z97 Deluxe](http://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/Z97DELUXE/) motherboard and Intel Core i5-4590S processor for an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS build.  My goal is to build a ZFS storage server and I'm thinking of this motherboard due to it supporting 10 SATA ports.

Does anyone have experience with this motherboard, particularly when plugging in a number of SATA drives?  I know that there are some limitations as pointed out by [Tyson Trautmann](https://askubuntu.com/users/58441/tyson-trautmann) in a previous [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507226/ubuntu-hangs-shows-a-black-screen-on-install-with-asus-z97-deluxe-gtx-770).

Thanks people, for any help you could offer on this topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about hardware recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

I finally decided to purchase the Asus Z97 Deluxe motherboard along with an Intel Core i5-4590S processor.  I'm happy to report that the board works fine with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  I'm also using the following SATA devices without any problems:

- 1 x 256 GB Samsung EVO 840 PRO for the Ubuntu OS
- 4 x Western Digital Caviar Red 3TB NAS drives a ZFS pool
- 1 x 256 GB Samsung EVO 840 PRO for the ZFS cache and ZFS Intent Log
- 1 x LG WH16NS40 Super Multi Blue Internal SATA 16x Blu-ray Disc Rewriter

So far, so good :-)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I'm also interested in that mainboard. Now, almost two weeks later, do you still haven't had any problems with the mainboard?